# How can I list ALL DNS records?

Tags: dns

Is there any way I can list ALL DNS records for a domain?

I know about such things as dig and nslookup but they only go so far. For example, if I've got a subdomain A record as

```
test A somedomain.co.uk
```

then unless I specifically ask for it, eg.

```
dig any test.somedomain.co.uk
```

I can't see it.

Is there any way (other than looking at the records by going to the DNS manager) to see exactly what all the DNS records are?

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/138949/list-all-dns-records-in-a-domain-using-dig/

Answer (score 263, accepted):

The short answer is that it's usually not possible, unless you control the domain.

## Option 1: ANY query

When you query for ANY, you will get a list of all records at that level but not below.

```
# try this
dig google.com any
```

This may return A records, TXT records, NS records, MX records, etc if the domain name is exactly "google.com". However, it will not return child records (e.g., [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)). More precisely, you MAY get these records if they exist.

The name server does not have to return these records if it chooses not to do so (for example, to reduce the size of the response). Most DNS servers reject ANY queries.

## Option 2: AXFR query

An AXFR is a zone transfer, and is likely what you want. However, these are typically restricted and not available unless you control the zone. You'll usually conduct a zone transfer directly from the authoritative server (the @ns1.google.com below) and often from a name server that may not be published (a stealth name server).

```
# This will return "Transfer failed"
dig @ns1.google.com google.com axfr
```

If you have control of the zone, you can set it up to get transfers that are protected with a TSIG key. This is a shared secret the client can send to the server to authorize the transfer.

## Option 3: Scrape with a script

Another option is to scrape all DNS records with a script. You'd have to iterate through all the DNS record types, and also through common subdomains, depending on your needs.

## Option 4: Use specialized tooling

There are some online tools that enumerate subdomains, and online tools that [list all DNS records](https://www.nslookup.io/) for a DNS name. Note that subdomain enumeration is usually not exhaustive.

Comment: Thanks for that(also to deltab).  Very clear explanation, confirming what I'd suspected - it is available but not to me (unless I start setting up my own nameservers).  

As I look after very many domains it would have been so nice just to run a script to get ALL the DNS entries.

Comment: Amazon's Route53 nameservers did not include TXT, MX and SOA when I tried this. After I specifically queried these records they where included in ANY answers. So take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: I just got "connection refused"

Comment: The spec has never been interpreted consistently by resolvers as to the meaning of ANY.  It definitely does not mean ALL (there's a request for that), although some (not many) treated it that way.  Others just dumped their cache, and others restricted it to certain record types.  In modern times (2016+), most providers have either disabled ANY (or give it a useless answer) or have plans to do so, as it is the common driver for many amplification attacks.

Comment: @NickBastin this draft (https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-dnsop-refuse-any-06) currently in the work tries to tighten up the pattern of replies for this query type. It also discuss why it is/should not be used.

Comment: This behaviour is not standard to all DNS servers, they might either refuse the query, or answer with all the subdomains.
The DNS standard only specifies that the * record (255) is "a request for all records"

Answer (score 44):

I've improved [Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405550/josh)'s answer. I've noticed that `dig` only shows entries already present in the queried nameserver's cache, so it's better to pull an authoritative nameserver from the SOA (rather than rely on the default nameserver). I've also disabled the filtering of wildcard IPs because usually I'm usually more interested in the correctness of the setup.

The new script takes a `-x` argument for expanded output and a `-s NS` argument to choose a specific nameserver: `dig -x example.com`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e; set -u
COMMON_SUBDOMAINS="www mail mx a.mx smtp pop imap blog en ftp ssh login"
EXTENDED=""

while :; do case "$1" in
  --) shift; break ;;
  -x) EXTENDED=y; shift ;;
  -s) NS="$2"; shift 2 ;;
  *) break ;;
esac; done
DOM="$1"; shift
TYPE="${1:-any}"

test "${NS:-}" || NS=$(dig +short  SOA "$DOM" | awk '{print $1}')
test "$NS" && NS="@$NS"

if test "$EXTENDED"; then
  dig +nocmd $NS "$DOM" +noall +answer "$TYPE"
  wild_ips=$(dig +short "$NS" "*.$DOM" "$TYPE" | tr '\n' '|')
  wild_ips="${wild_ips%|}"
  for sub in $COMMON_SUBDOMAINS; do
    dig +nocmd $NS "$sub.$DOM" +noall +answer "$TYPE"
  done | cat  #grep -vE "${wild_ips}"
  dig +nocmd $NS "*.$DOM" +noall +answer "$TYPE"
else
  dig +nocmd $NS "$DOM" +noall +answer "$TYPE"
fi
```

Comment: add lines `dig -t txt +nocmd $NS "$DOM" +noall +answer` (and modify the `$DOM`) to inspect the TXT records of a domain.

Comment: That should be `dig -t txt +nocmd $NS "$DOM" +noall +answer "$TYPE"` and it goes inside the `if test "$EXTENDED"; then` block,

Answer (score 28):

`host -a` works well, similar to `dig any`.

EG:

```
$ host -a google.com
Trying "google.com"
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 10403
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 18, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0


;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  ANY

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     1165    IN  TXT "v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ip4:216.73.93.70/31 ip4:216.73.93.72/31 ~all"
google.com.     53965   IN  SOA ns1.google.com. dns-admin.google.com. 2014112500 7200 1800 1209600 300
google.com.     231 IN  A   173.194.115.73
google.com.     231 IN  A   173.194.115.78
google.com.     231 IN  A   173.194.115.64
google.com.     231 IN  A   173.194.115.65
google.com.     231 IN  A   173.194.115.66
google.com.     231 IN  A   173.194.115.67
google.com.     231 IN  A   173.194.115.68
google.com.     231 IN  A   173.194.115.69
google.com.     231 IN  A   173.194.115.70
google.com.     231 IN  A   173.194.115.71
google.com.     231 IN  A   173.194.115.72
google.com.     128 IN  AAAA    2607:f8b0:4000:809::1001
google.com.     40766   IN  NS  ns3.google.com.
google.com.     40766   IN  NS  ns4.google.com.
google.com.     40766   IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
google.com.     40766   IN  NS  ns2.google.com.
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is how to find other records in the DNS zone of a domain, i.e. additionally all records for subdomains. That's not to say `host -a` isn't a useful command, it just doesn't do what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 21):

In the absence of the ability to do zone transfers, I wrote this small bash script, `dg`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
COMMON_SUBDOMAINS=(www mail smtp pop imap blog en ftp ssh login)
if [[ "$2" == "x" ]]; then
    dig +nocmd "$1" +noall +answer "${3:-any}"
    wild_ips="$(dig +short "*.$1" "${3:-any}" | tr '\n' '|')"
    wild_ips="${wild_ips%|}"
    for sub in "${COMMON_SUBDOMAINS[@]}"; do
        dig +nocmd "$sub.$1" +noall +answer "${3:-any}"
    done | grep -vE "${wild_ips}"
    dig +nocmd "*.$1" +noall +answer "${3:-any}"
else
    dig +nocmd "$1" +noall +answer "${2:-any}"
fi
```

Now I use `dg example.com` to get a nice, clean list of DNS records, or `dg example.com x` to include a bunch of other popular subdomains.

`grep -vE "${wild_ips}"` filters out records that could be the result of a wildcard DNS entry such as `* 10800 IN A 1.38.216.82`. Otherwise, a wildcard entry would make it appear as if there were records for each `$COMMON_SUBDOMAN`.

Note: This relies on `ANY` queries, which are [blocked by some DNS providers such as CloudFlare](https://blog.cloudflare.com/deprecating-dns-any-meta-query-type/).

Comment: I know this solution is far from ideal, but it's saved me a lot of time, so I hope it'll be useful to someone else.

Comment: add `dig -t txt +nocmd "$1" +noall +answer` (and modify to `"*.$1"` etc.) to inspect the TXT records of a domain.

Answer (score 18):

**For Windows:**

You may find the need to check the status of your domains DNS records, or check the Name Servers to see which records the servers are pulling.

1. Launch Windows Command Prompt by navigating to Start > Command Prompt or via Run > CMD.
2. Type NSLOOKUP and hit Enter.  The default Server is set to your local DNS, the Address will be your local IP.
3. Set the DNS Record type you wish to lookup by typing `set type=##` where ## is the record type, then hit Enter.  You may use ANY, A, AAAA, A+AAAA, CNAME, MX, NS, PTR, SOA, or SRV as the record type.
4. Now enter the domain name you wish to query then hit Enter..  In this example, we will use Managed.com.
5. NSLOOKUP will now return the record entries for the domain you entered.
6. You can also change the Name Servers which you are querying.  This is useful if you are checking the records before DNS has fully propagated.  To change the Name Server type server [name server].  Replace [name server] with the Name Servers you wish to use.  In this example, we will set these as NSA.managed.com.
7. Once changed, change the query type (Step 3) if needed then enter new a new domain (Step 4.)

**For Linux:**

1. Check DNS Records Using Dig Command
   Dig stands for domain information groper is a flexible tool for interrogating DNS name servers. It performs DNS lookups and displays the answers that are returned from the name server(s) that were queried. Most DNS administrators use dig to troubleshoot DNS problems because of its flexibility, ease of use and clarity of output. Other lookup tools tend to have less functionality than dig.
2. Check DNS Records Using NSlookup Command
   Nslookup is a program to query Internet domain name servers. Nslookup has two modes interactive and non-interactive.

   Interactive mode allows the user to query name servers for information about various hosts and domains or to print a list of hosts in a domain.

   Non-interactive mode is used to print just the name and requested information for a host or domain. It’s network administration tool which will help them to check and troubleshoot DNS related issues.
3. Check DNS Records Using Host Command
   host is a simple utility for performing DNS lookups. It is normally used to convert names to IP addresses and vice versa. When no arguments or options are given, host prints a short summary of its command line arguments and options.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me in Windows 7, but appears to be buggy in Windows 10, this is what I used to debug a TXT record in Windows 10:

nslookup -querytype=txt yourdomainnamehere.com

Comment: And, as last reminder, use 'ls' argument of nslookup command. For example: 1) nslookup 2) server 89.179.244.127 3) ls ok-dancetour.ru. Attention! DOT in end of domain name - it is essential, 'ok-dancetour.ru' and 'ok-dancetour.ru.' - these are different names

Comment: Did this for google.com and only got one ip back, this seems wrong

Comment: This answer appears to be plagiarized from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/65182/how-to-find-all-possible-dns-records-for-a-server

Comment: @tripleee this was posted 2019, the Learn Microsoft article 2020, so I'd say it is the other way around...

Comment: There seem to be multiple sources. The Windows part appears to be stolen from https://support.managed.com/kb/a2312/how-to-use-nslookup-to-view-your-dns-records.aspx while much of the Linux stuff is copy/pasted from man pages. In any event, not original content.

Answer (score 16):

1. A zone transfer is the only way to be sure you have all the subdomain records. If the DNS is correctly configured you should not normally be able to perform an external zone transfer.
2. The [scans.io](https://scans.io) project has a database of DNS records that can be downloaded and searched for subdomains. This requires downloading the 87GB of DNS data, alternatively you can try the online search of the data at https://hackertarget.com/find-dns-host-records/

Answer (score 12):

What you want is called a **zone transfer**. You can request a zone transfer using `dig -t axfr`.

A **zone** is a domain and all of the domains below it that are not delegated to another server.

Note that zone transfers are not always supported. They're not used in normal lookup, only in replicating DNS data between servers; but there are other protocols that can be used for that (such as rsync over ssh), there may be a security risk from exposing names, and zone transfer responses cost more to generate and send than usual DNS lookups.

Answer (score 12):

Many DNS servers refuse ‘ANY’ queries. So the only way is to query for every type individually. Luckily there are sites that make this simpler. For example, https://www.nslookup.io shows the most popular record types by default, and has support for all existing record types.

Comment: Correct answer.
The original rationale was that a server could have a huge amount of dns records, so ANY was made optional. Since implementation on sites with lots of records (think a subdomain for each user ) would leave them open to DOS attacks or would require pagination.
In the current era, this was never rectified because once the rules were set, they calcified, DNS servers might rightfully consider their records confidential, an ANY query might allow user enumeration if each user gets a subdomain.

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to get all DNS records for a domain in one instance.
You can only view certain records for example, if you wanna see an A record for a certain domain you can use the command: dig a(type of record) domain.com. This is the same for all the other type of records you wanna see for that domain.

If your not familiar with the command line interface, you can also use a site like https://mxtoolbox.com. Which is very handy tool for getting records of a domain.

Answer (score -1):

```
dig @8.8.8.8 example.domain any
```

will list all the DNS records. Here `8.8.8.8` is Google's DNS.

Comment: This is absolutely incorrect. `any` never meant `all`.  At best it shows you all records **currently in the resolver cache** which is certainly not all records that can exist and will have varying results depending on which nameserver you query and when. Plus newer standards make resolvers not even bothering anymore replying to `ANY` queries. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8482.txt